# Difficulty displaying an Input with Icon using Lightning Design System

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I'm working on creating a Visualforce page that uses the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/). As part of the VF page I'm trying to include an text input field which the user will use to input search terms.  I would like to use the [Input with icon to the right](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#flavor-input) displaying a magnifying glass icon per the standard SLDS markup.

```
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-input__icon slds-icon-text-default">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
      </svg>
      <input id="text-input-01" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text">
    </div>
  </div>
```

My problem is that the input field does not display at all. [image: Label without input box]

When I inspect the element I find that the `input` field is being placed inside the `svg` tag.  [image: Input tag inside svg tag]

I have found that if I put a `span` or `div` tag around the `input` tag then the `input` tag will be outside of the `svg` tag like it is supposed to be and it will display the input box but the magnifying glass icon does not display.[image] [image]

I have the most recent version of SLDS and the markup is directly copied from the Lightning Design System website.  What is going wrong and how can I get the magnifying glass to display properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line of code, this path should refer to your SLDS library which you uploaded in Static resources.

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search"></use>
```

For example:

```
<use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS100, '/assets/icons/custom-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#custom3')}" />
```

Comment: >,<  Why is it always the stupidest things.  argghh.  So that gets me the magnifying icon when my input is surrounded by `span` tags.  Any idea why when I remove the `span` tags the `input` tag gets shoved inside the `svg` tag?

Comment: hmm. not sure about that

Comment: @SFNinja now that SLDS is baked into Lighting Experience, how would we go about this sort of thing now?